# Mock ExecutorService and Lambda expression for unit test in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, executorservice, powermockito

My code base is similar to this, where based on the input parameters, I create object using lambda expression. (The reason why I use lambda expression to create object in parallel is because of object creation operation is costly).

```
private List<Future<MyObj1>> myObj1FutureList = new ArrayList<>();
 for (String key : keys) {
  Future<MyObj1> myObj1Future = executorService.submit(() -> new MyObj1(AnyObject, Arrays.asList(key),"AnyString",AnyObject,null,AnyObject));
  myObj1FutureList.add(myObj1Future);
            }
```

I am writing unit test cases for this. where I have to mock executor service as well as lambda expression. 
I am using similar test cases

```
    Future<MyObj1> myObj1Future1 = mock(Future.class);
    MyObj1 myObj1 = mock(MyObj1.class);
    when(myObj1Future1.get()).thenReturn(myObj1);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(MyObj1.class).withArguments(eq(obj1), eq(Arrays.asList(myObj1)), anyString(), any(),any(), any()).thenReturn(myObj1);
    when(executorService.submit(() -> myObj1)).thenReturn(myObj1Future1);
```

But I have observed that, value of mocked object is coming null. 
Am I missing something here? Please suggest.

Just to add more information, MyObj1 has 6 arguments in constructor. 
Note: Though powermockito is costly to use, I see only this possible option. 
Please suggest any other possible option.

Comment: It would be nice to properly format your posted code to make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: My Bad. While changing names because of privacy issues, I forgot to reformat.

Comment: Isn't it a bit over the top to mock `Future` and `MyObj1`? Any implementation of `Future` would be a pretty simple class in itself that doesn't rely on anything costly or external. Same for `MyObj1` if it is a POJO.

Comment: MyObj1 is not POJO. It has some complex objects. For some objects, it makes service calls for dependency graphs and fetches data. So, in unit tests, I have to mock that also.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complexifying your test.

This is what it should look like:

```
MyObj1 result1 = new MyObj1(...); // Use whatever parameters you want.
MyObj1 result2 = new MyObj1(...); // Use whatever parameters you want.
Future<MyObj1> future1 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result1);
Future<MyObj1> future2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result2);
when(executorService.submit(Mockito.<Callable<MyObj1>>any()))
  .thenReturn(future1, future2);
```

Rules out of the thumb:

- Don't mock your pojos or pojo-like constructs (`MyObj1` and `Future`).
- Use the most basic pojo-like items of your more complex object. In the case of `Future`, it's `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(obj)`.

Comment: I have yo create Mock of MyObj1, since in actual code, it calls other micro services and fetches data. So in test, I have to avoid that.

Comment: What are you testing? `MyObj1` or some other class? If you're testing `MyObj1`, you should have it wrapped in a `Future` at all. If no, just mock it: `MyObj1 obj = mock(MyObj1.class);`. If you can't because of the arguments, extract an interface out of the `MyObj1` class and mock that interface.

Comment: I agree, I need to test class not object.  I tried with this approach same it is. But not working. method is not being mocked. I guess, since inside executor service's submit, lambda expression is there. that is why it is not working.